# VS 2017 Community - Cannont find or open the PDB file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, pdb-files

Installed Visual Studio 2017 Community on a new Windows 10 machine. 
Created a simple Hello World sample and it fails to execute. 
Most symbols load, but there are a couple which fail.

```
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Training\VC-Simple\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
**'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\guard32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.**
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
**'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cssguard32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.**
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
**The thread 0x4f14 has exited with code 0 (0x0).**
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[20556] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have done what a number of threads have suggested :
Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols : Check "Microsoft Symbol Server

Changing the above settings did clean up the errors a bit but this is the current output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad....
I saw the errors and assumed there were still issues. 
The Console window was appearing but then quickly disappearing. 
After adding : Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)
it seems to be behaving as expected now.